# absolute values of algebraic numbers under Galois automorphism

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

This could be very easy question, but I have no idea about it in depth.

> **Q.** Let $\alpha$ be an algebraic integer. Let $\sigma$ be an automorphism of Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ (over $\mathbb{Q}$). If, as complex number, $|\alpha|<1$, is it necessary that $|\sigma(\alpha)|<1$?

Comment: In fact, it can *never* be the case that $|\sigma(\alpha)| < 1$ for all $\sigma$ unless $\alpha = 0$, since otherwise the product of all the conjugates would also be less than $1$, yet it must also be a rational integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, no.

For example, let $\alpha = 2-\sqrt{2},\,$ and consider the automorphism $\sigma$ of $\mathbb{Q}(a)$ such that $\sigma(\sqrt{2}) = -\sqrt{2}$.

Then

$$|a| = |2-\sqrt{2}| < 1$$

but

$$|\sigma(a)| = |2+\sqrt{2}| > 1$$

Comment: May I draw your attention to the Pisot numbers, which are *real* algebraic numbers  > 1, and such that all their other conjugates have module < 1. They possess many intriguing properties related to diophantine approximation, Fourier series, distribution (mod 1), the golden ratio, etc. See the Wikipedia article on this subject.